# Amazon AWA - No class Def found exception

Tags: java, netbeans, amazon-s3

I had deployed to a cloud glassfish server and getting this error. 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonClientException

I do not have access to CLASS_PATH since it is cloud environment. Any
glassfish setting i can configured? It works locally on my machine.

The error was thrown when initializing a class that referenced to

```
 import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
 import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
 import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
 import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
 import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
 import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.*;
```

Maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
<version>1.3.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked with the Maven and Glassfish combination but I did run into the same type of problem with Tomcat.

The issue in my case was that I did not configure the Eclipse development environment to package the Maven dependencies for the Tomcat server.  To do this for Eclipse,  properties -> "Deployment Assembly".  Click "Add" and select "Build Path Entities" then choose "Maven Dependencies".

This will allow Eclipse WTP to push the Maven dependencies to the Tomcat Server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it is a little bit frustrating. @nadnavillus's answer helped me. But slight change.
If you are working on Eclipse.

Go to , ***Project Properties-> "Deployment Assembly"-> Go to "Add"-> Select AWS SDK Libraries***. Provided, you have Amazon SDK downloaded on your system.

Comment: @BaradwajAryasomayajula If you are using maven. then don't go for this. It will give you errors of duplicate dependencies. It is if you are not using Maven Dependencies.

Comment: Ok..... Had to change everything for my home work.... But when I implemented the code using the servlets, I am able to display all the buckets in my S3... But unable to upload any files into it.... But the same code when implemented in pure java it worked fine..... Do you have any idea....

Comment: It seems like you are not having write privileges, add privileges to your scope.

Comment: But we are able to upload the data from the normal java project and display them.....

Comment: Add some sample code in edit , it's a little hazy without it

Answer (score 0):

Try building it from Command Line(mvn clean install). I experienced similar issues with other dependencies while building it from eclipse.